# earliest date for a combination of Id and code

Tags: r

I have a dataset as shown below

```
   Id        Date        Code
   1232      2011-05-27  NFS
   1323      2012-02-12  NFS
   1355      2009-12-11  CSX
   1221      2011-10-17  WBT
   1232      2004-06-05  CSX
   1355      2007-08-15  CSX
```

The objective is to create three date columns, one for each code {Early_NFS_DATE, Early_CSX_DATE, Early_WBT_DATE}. These Date columns should store the earliest/smallest date for each **Id and code**, combo, for example:

Id 1232 contains two codes NFS and CSX. The earliest date for ID 1232 and Code NFS is 2011-05-27 so the Early_NFS_DATE column should contain date 2011-05-27.

The earliest date for ID 1232 and Code CSX is 2004-06-05 so the Early_CSX_DATE column should contain date 2004-06-05.

Id 1355 only contains one code CSX and the earliest date for ID 1355 and Code CSX is 2007-08-15 so the Early_CSX_DATE column should contain date 2007-08-15...so on

The output should look like this below.

```
   Id        Date        Code    Early_NFS_DATE   Early_CSX_DATE     Early_WBT_DATE
   1232      2011-05-27  NFS     2011-05-27       2004-06-05         .
   1323      2012-02-12  NFS     2012-02-12       .                  .
   1355      2009-12-11  CSX     .                2007-08-15         . 
   1221      2011-10-17  WBT     .                .                  2011-10-17                                
   1232      2004-06-05  CSX     2011-05-27       2004-06-05         .
   1355      2007-08-15  CSX     .                2007-08-15         .
```

Need help doing this.

Comment: Hi, your output is not clear since you said <<These Date columns should store the earliest/smallest date for each Id and code>>, but `Early_NFS_DATE` and `Early_CSX_DATE` contains dates that do not correspond the `Code` column, so what is the point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for example :

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
dx$Date <- as.Date(dx$Date)
dx_w <- dcast(dx,Code+Id~Code,
      function(x) {if (length(x)>0) min(x) else NA_real_},value.var="Date")
setDT(dx_w)[,lapply(.SD,as.Date,origin="1970-01-01"),"Id,Code"]

#     Id Code        CSX        NFS        WBT
# 1: 1232  CSX 2004-06-05       <NA>       <NA>
# 2: 1355  CSX 2007-08-15       <NA>       <NA>
# 3: 1232  NFS       <NA> 2011-05-27       <NA>
# 4: 1323  NFS       <NA> 2012-02-12       <NA>
# 5: 1221  WBT       <NA>       <NA> 2011-10-17
```

1. Use `dcast` to put your data in the wide format but this transform  Dates to numeric. Note the use of `Code` in the 2 terms of the formula.
2. So a second step to transform numeric dates created to real dates.
3. You maybe need an extra step to format your result( renaming column and changing missing values..)

---

From [`data.table v 1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), we don't need to load `reshape2` and `dcast` preserves attributes (which eliminates the last step). That is,

```
require(data.table) # v 1.9.5
setDT(dx)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
dcast(dx, Id + Code ~ Code, fun=min, fill=NA, value.var="Date")
#      Id Code        CSX        NFS        WBT
# 1: 1221  WBT       <NA>       <NA> 2011-10-17
# 2: 1232  CSX 2004-06-05       <NA>       <NA>
# 3: 1232  NFS       <NA> 2011-05-27       <NA>
# 4: 1323  NFS       <NA> 2012-02-12       <NA>
# 5: 1355  CSX 2007-08-15       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: @Arun thanks for you edit.  When I tried you code on widows I get this error `Error in frankv(dat, cols = cols, ties.method = "dense") : 
  Internal error: invalid ties.method for frankv()` . In my sessionInfo I have : `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)-Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)-other attached packages:[1] data.table_1.9.5`

Comment: I just updated my data.table version before posting my last comment. Using `install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`. So I think I already have the last commit. Maybe should I update my R version?

Comment: Hm.. strange. Maybe uninstall first, and then reinstall and try again (this has fixed the issue on some occasions)... I don't think R version should be related.

Comment: @Arun this didn't fix the problem. Even for the vignette code, When I test ` DT <- melt(as.data.table(ChickWeight), id=2:4). I get an error : `Argument 'verbose' should be logical TRUE/FALSE`. Same error when i set verbose argument. I will take a closer look once I have more time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test on Windows too. I've fixed some bug reports from Windows users, but this one never turned up... PS: don't load `reshape2`. If you're, then load it before loading `data.table`.

Comment: @Arun, when I tried your approach I got an error Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : 
  values must be type 'logical',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'

Comment: @KingFrazier, you're not using `data.table`'s `melt`, but `reshape2`'s. Remove your current installation of data.table, install 1.9.5 following the instructions, don't load `reshape2` (or load it before data.table), and then try again. `vapply(...)` code is from `reshape2`.